# Matlab x=[x[i]]; means?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to understand a matlab code, but I'm not familiar with matlab much. Can someone please tell me what the meaning of x = [ x[i] ] is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about this then? DG = [sum(G)]

Comment: @Bhathiya: you should read the MATLAB documentation, it has a nice "getting started" entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression really must be read as

```
x = [ x [i] ]
```

Focusing on the right side, you are making a joined matrix (i.e., joining columns) of x along with a 1x1 matrix given by `i` (which may be a matrix itself, obviously). Then you are assigning it to another variable, `x` in this case.

I must remind you that access to indices is made using round parentheses.

Comment: "I must remind you that access to indices is made using round parentheses." Thanks a lot for this one too.

Answer (score 3):

`[]` is used to concatenate matrices.  e.g.:

```
a = 3;
b = 2;
c = [a b]

c = 
       3     2
```

Your code can be written with spaces to clarify:

```
x = [x [i]];
```

i.e. there are two nested uses of the concatenation operator.  But doing something like `[i]` is pointless; it's equivalent to just `i`. i.e. your code is equivalent to:

```
x = [x i];
```

i.e. it concatenates `x` with `i`, and then assigns the result back to `x`.